# Get each value from a string via std::ifstream

Tags: c++, get, std, ifstream

I am try to use an `ifstream` with the while loop to get each value. However, when I try it, nothing happens. Why?

```
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line);
std::ifstream stream(line);
while(stream){
    std::cout << stream.get();
}
```

Comment: Wait, do you want to extract values from `line` or from a file whose name is in `line`?

Comment: @Medinoc - From `line` itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use an `istringstream`, not an `ifstream`.